# Objective C class category in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, categories

I have created a class category in Objective C:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (LayerProperties)

@property IBInspectable (nonatomic) CGFloat cornerRadius;
@property IBInspectable (nonatomic) CGFloat borderWidth;
@property IBInspectable (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *borderColour;

@end
```

This is all good and works if I import the header.  How do I get this category to show up in Interface Builder when I add a UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being dumb.  All that is wrong is that I have put the IBInspectable macro in the wrong place in my property definition:

```
@property IBInspectable (nonatomic) CGFloat cornerRadius;
```

Should be:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;
```

Silly mistake, might help someone else save some time.  Now all properties show up on all views (and view subclasses):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. KVC in interface builder. Maybe you need subclass

[image]

Or Create subclass and use `IBInspectable / IBDesignable`
(http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/ )

Comment: Thanks Sudir, I am using IBInspectable, but I would like to apply these properties to the existing UIView class without subclassing so that existing UIViews in Interface Builder/Storyboards show up with the extra properties.  Is this possible without subclassing?

Comment: You can do this check **More Advanced Uses** section in this link for detail
http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/user-defined-runtime-attributes/

Comment: But, you need to do this for each and every class right? What if I want to add an additional property? I will need to add it to each class then.

Comment: I figured it out (see my answer), I was being dumb. It works very well straight out of the box.  For instance I have a subclass of a view called GradientView, which is also IBDesginable and has IBInspectable properties.  This now shows both sets of properties in the inspector without the need to manually add anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass a view where you should import this category. And then change your storyboard view with that subclassed view, all the properties from your category should be available then.

For e.g.

```
#import "LayerProperties+UIView.h"
@interface MyCustomView : UIView
@end
```

Now in IB, change your view class to `MyCustomView`.

Comment: Thanks Hemang, I would like to apply these properties to the existing UIView class without subclassing so that existing UIViews in Interface Builder/Storyboards show up with the extra properties. Is this possible without subclassing?